# Scalarize a list

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I need a function that unwraps a singleton atom from an arbitrary nested list and returns all other expressions unchanged. I have come up with the following solution:

```
Scalarize[x_List] := If[ Union@Dimensions@x == {1}, First@Level[x, {-1}], x ]
Scalarize[x_] := x
```

Some example usages:

```
Scalarize[{1}]
```

> 1

```
Scalarize[{{1}}]
```

> 1

```
Scalarize[{1, 2}]
```

> {1, 2}

```
Scalarize[{}]
```

> {}

The list does not have to be rectangular:

```
Scalarize[{{1, 2}, 3}]
```

> {{1, 2}, 3}

I wonder if there is a builtin function that I am missing or if there is a more efficient way to do that.

Comment: I'd use `First@Flatten[x]` rather than `Level`, but it doesn't really matter until the number of nested levels gets fairly large.

Comment: Entries are atomic, i.e., Integers, Reals or Strings.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess your solution does not work on `{{}, {2}}`?  Shouldn't it return `2`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 No. Empty lists need to be preserved.

Comment: Then I think your solution is pretty good. (Aside from `Flatten`, in general I'd use `DeleteDuplicates` instead of `Union` for efficiency, but the length of `Dimensions` is likely to be too short to matter.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a refactoring of the OP's idea:

```
scalarize // ClearAll;
scalarize[x_List] /; MatchQ[MinMax@Dimensions@x, {1, 1}] := 
  First@Flatten[x];
scalarize[x_] := x;
```

Another way:

```
scalarize // ClearAll;
scalarize[x_List] :=
  CheckAbort[
   x /. {Except[{_}, _List] :> Abort[]}; First@Flatten@x,
   x];
scalarize[x_] := x;
```

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps something like that:

```
Scalarize[x_List]:=If[Length[Flatten[x]]==1,Identity@@Flatten[x],x]
```

Comment: [According to the OP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/278626/scalarize-a-list#comment695828_278626) `Scalarize[{{}, {2}}]` should return `{{}, {2}}`, not `2`. (That's NOT how I understood the problem as stated in the opening paragraph, though. I would have gone for `Flatten`-based approach, too.)

Answer (score 4):

There is a built-in function for checking whether an expression is atomic: `AtomQ`. So, if your definition of atomic matches Mathematica's, you could do something like:

```
Scalarize[list_List] :=
  With[
    {flat = Flatten[list]},
    If[
      MatchQ[flat, {_?AtomQ}],
      First@flat,
      list]];
Scalarize[other_] := other;
```

You don't really need the `With`, I just don't like repeating expressions.

Your examples are all with numbers, so if `AtomQ` doesn't match your semantics, maybe `NumberQ` would.

Or, based on your update, maybe some combination of `NumberQ` and `StringQ`.